# Oculus as normal window 10 mouse

Tags: windows-10, mouse, cursor, mouse-cursor, oculus-rift

Seems the handheld device of Oculus VR is called oculus touch.

Is there any way to use the oculus touch as a win10 mouse? (it is fine to switch on the headset）

So when I swing the device in the air, the pointer will move in window10.

Answer (score 0):

Oculus touch works with the headset.

You can't couple it to other devices.

You could perhaps use it the other way around, to:
[access apps from your computer's desktop inside your VR experience](https://support.oculus.com/166993604065478/).

Comment: It is fine to let the headset on but definitely not on my head,   could I turn on the headset and put it on the table?

Comment: Nothing prevents you from doing anything that is useful to you.